# jquery forward slash escape

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I escape forward slash `/`

```
$('<script type="text/javascript" />').prependTo("head");
```

the outcome is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

but I need it like

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
```

I know I could add `</script>` but I just would like to know if there is a way to escape `/`
Thanks.

Comment: You escape it like this: `\/` but should you not be doing `$('<script type="text/javascript"></script>')` Also, it is an empty `script` tag which is not serving any purpose

Comment: Why are you adding an empty `<script>` tag in the first place?

Comment: Note that `type="text/javascript"` is assumed if no `type` attribute is present. This was made official in HTML5. Just a tip to save some typing...

Answer (score 5):

The [`<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) tag is not self-closing, which means that the `/>` notation doesn't work. The below is the only correct way to define a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Of course, an empty script doesn't seem to make too much practical sense, but I don't judge.